# Time complexity boost regex

Tags: regex, boost, time, complexity-theory

How can I evaluate time complexity of matching a regex using boost?

Does it only depend on the length and the recurrency or is anything else involved?

For example, let's assume I do have this regex that matches any alphanumeric string

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

and I have a function like this

```
bool isAlphanumerical(string str){
  return boost::regex_match(str, "[A-Za-z0-9]+");
}
```

is there a way to tell what's its time complexity?
what about if I add some cases like this (I also changed the former regex in order to only match combinations of numbers and capital letters ) :

```
[A-Z0-9]+$|\s*$|_*$
```

so that I can also match strings only containing spaces or hypens?

And what if I also recur over the pattern like this

```
(?i)[A-Z0-9]+$|\s*$|_*$
```

?

Comment: `[A-z]` [does not only match letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970). Replaced with `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: thanks! What about the complexity?